# Expected number of request at a given time, knowing requests per minute and average request processing length

Tags: statistics

Imagine a server that takes requests from clients and returns a response to them. We model it by assuming a certain average number of requests received per minute (let's say 100), and also by assuming an average time it takes to process a request (let's say 0.1 seconds). For simplicity, we assume that the server can take and process an arbitrary number of requests in parallel.

I would like to calculate the expected number of requests that are being processed at any given moment.

What kind of approach should I take? What other assumptions I will also need to make the calculation possible?

Comment: You'll need a model for the request process.  Standard would be a Poisson distribution (implementing the assumption that a request is equally likely to come in at any time).  That distribution has the problem that it scales.  That is to say, the distribution of requests in a specified $.1$ second window is again Poisson with the appropriately scaled parameter.

Comment: @lulu If you receive on average $100$ requests a minute, and process each in an average of $\frac1{600}$ of a minute, then a natural guess for the expected number of requests that are being processed at any given moment is $\frac16$.  Can you find a case where that does not apply?  Your clustering would lead to more being processed in parallel (pushing up the expectation) but also more time when none are being processed (pushing down the expectation)

Comment: @Henry  Ah, you are right. If we have $N$ requests, they consume $N\times .1$ seconds of processing time, and that's all you need to know.  Thanks.  I'll delete that comment.

Comment: @Henry that argument sounds reasonable, can you please write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Requested from comments:*

If you receive on average $100$ requests a minute, and process each in an average of $\frac1{600}$ of a minute, then a natural guess for the expected number of requests that are being processed at any given moment is $\frac16$.